# django-autocomplete-light generic foreign key invalid view function

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light, generic-foreign-key

I am trying to use django autocomplete light to set up [Autocompletion for GenericForeignKey](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/gfk.html)

However I am getting this error when I try to view the form:

[image]

I have a simple a setup. But because the urls are in an app's namespace, it can't find them.

**models.py**

```
class Prereq(IsAPrereqMixin, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

    prereq_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='prereq_item',
                                            verbose_name="Type of Prerequisite",
                                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prereq_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Prerequisite")
    prereq_object = GenericForeignKey("prereq_content_type", "prereq_object_id")

    # lots more fields ignored for now
```

**forms.py**

```
from dal import autocomplete
from prerequisites.models import Prereq

class PrereqForm(autocomplete.FutureModelForm):

    prereq_object = autocomplete.Select2GenericForeignKeyModelField(
        model_choice=[(Prereq, "Prereq"), ]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Prereq
        fields = ['name']
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from prerequisites import views
from prerequisites.forms import PrereqForm

app_name = 'prerequisites'

urlpatterns = [
    path('edit/<int:pk>/', views.PrereqUpdateView.as_view(), name='prereq_edit'),
]

#  https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/gfk.html#register-the-view-for-the-form
urlpatterns.extend(PrereqForm.as_urls())
```

Comment: It might be to do with your namespaced urls, the correct pattern name will be prefixed with `"prerequisites:"`, does removing `app_name = 'prerequisites'` from your urls.py fix the issue?

Comment: Yes it does, if I also remove the namespace from the app's url pattern when it's included with the project.  Although now my app doesn't have the namespace I want =D